# Want to supply Hot Indian Tea to few companies, How can I keep it hot for hours withot losing taste

Tags: tea, chai

I Tried Milton 3ltr with press button on it but after few hours the taste gets change. I want a right product to keep it fresh as prepared for more then 6 hours. What's the right way to do that so that I will increase the supply area to reach maximum.

Answer (score 5):

There's a reason it's termed "Fresh Brewed". Tea and coffee only stay fresh for so long. It can be kept hot, not fresh.

Answer (score 4):

Make your own chai concentrate and mix it with boiling-hot water.

You cannot reasonably keep brewed tea hot for 6-8 hours without it degrading in quality.  What you can do, though, is [brew a chai concentrate](https://masalaandchai.com/chai-concentrate/) which you can keep at room temperature.  You then carry around sealed thermoses full of boiling hot water, or an electric quick-boil pot if you have access to electricity.  If you need to rely on the thermoses, these need to be [real vacuum-walled glass thermoses](https://www.popularmechanics.com/adventure/outdoor-gear/g3089/best-thermos/) in order to keep the water above 90C for several hours.  You should have several smaller ones rather than one giant one, because that way some can stay sealed and hot as long as possible.

Then, when you want to serve a customer, you mix 1/4 concentrate and 3/4 hot water, and milk.  The result will be hot chai.

(the above is the advice of a friend who works in catering)